# How Sum and Group By in stored procedure before Insert to other table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have tables `Purchasing.tblGoodsReceive` (tableA) and `Accounting.tblGeneralLedger` (tableB).

I want to write a stored procedure to insert data into tableA and then insert into tableB, but in tableB I want to insert only Sum and Group By.

For illustration see the screenshot.

```
INSERT INTO Purchasing.tblGoodsReceive (GoodsReceiveID, DateReceived, DeliveryOrder, VendorID, Warehouse, PostingToGJ, ReceivedBy, CheckedBy, CorrectionBy, ApprovedBy, AcceptedBy, CreatedBy)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @NewID(ID)
VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5, @Param5a, @Param6, @Param6a, @Param6b, @Param6c, @Param6d, @Param7);

MERGE Purchasing.tblGoodsRecieveDetail AS old
USING (SELECT 
           x.value('ID[1]', 'int') AS ID,
           x.value('GoodsRecieveID[1]', 'int') AS GoodsRecieveID,
           x.value('NoInvoice[1]', 'int') AS NoInvoice,
           x.value('NoPO[1]', 'int') AS OrderID,
           x.value('ItemID[1]', 'int') AS ItemID,
           x.value('ReceivedQty[1]', 'int') AS ReceivedQty,
           x.value('UnitPrice[1]', 'money') AS UnitPrice,
           x.value('Complete[1]', 'bit') AS Complete,
           @ParamRateItem AS RateID
       FROM 
           @ParamXml1.nodes('/NewDataSet/vItemsReceivingItem') XmlData(x)) AS new ON (new.ID = old.ID)

    WHEN NOT MATCHED AND new.ItemID IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 
        INSERT (GoodsReceiveID, NoInvoice, OrderID, ItemCode, ReceivedQty, UnitPrice, Complete, RateID)
        Values((SELECT ID FROM @NewID), new.NoInvoice, new.OrderID, new.ItemID, new.ReceivedQty, new.UnitPrice, new.Complete, new.RateID);
```

For illustration see the screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUItd.png)

Comment: Can you provide the SQL query of your INSERT statement into table A.

Comment: INSERT (GoodsRecieveID,NoInvoice,OrderID,ItemCode,ReceivedQty,UnitPrice,Complete,RateID)
            Values((select ID from @NewID),new.NoInvoice,new.OrderID,new.ItemID,new.ReceivedQty,new.UnitPrice,new.Complete,new.RateID);


im using Xml to insert tableA

Comment: Do you have an UPDATE query that sets the column 'COMPLETE' to true?

Comment: your screenshot and your above script are not in tandem.Why are you using xml variable to insert into TableB ?As per you screenshot, where is your AccountID in script ?